# Isotope relayout method error, no such a method

Tags: javascript, html

Sorry if i am not the first, but is the isotope relayout method works? Did they change it or I am doing something wrong?

I have a container with images. At some moment I need to replace images with new images and I need to 'relayout' the container.

```
$('#container').isotope('reLayout');
```

This method returns:

```
no such method 'reLayout' for isotope instance
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

If somebody meets the problem like I did:

They have renamed the method from 'reLayout' to 'layout'. 
Watch Appendix on their official site